# Proof of cauchy's third inequality

Tags: inequality

Show that for positive $h_i, b_i$ where $h_i / b_i \leq h_j/b_j$ if $i < j$ that the following inequality holds

$$\frac{h_1}{b_1} \leq \frac{\sum_i^n h_i}{\sum_i^nb_i} \leq \frac{h_n}{b_n}$$

My proof uses the mean value theorem to prove this result, but I am looking for alternative proofs. Specifically I wonder if it's possible to prove this with some variation of the rearrangement inequality.

Comment: This is the “mediant inequality” – duplicate target found [with Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Cfrac%7Bh_1%7D%7Bb_1%7D%20%5Cleq%20%5Cfrac%7B%5Csum_i%5En%20h_i%7D%7B%5Csum_i%5Enb_i%7D%20%5Cleq%20%5Cfrac%7Bh_n%7D%7Bb_n%7D%24)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align}
\frac{h_i}{b_i}\le\frac{h_n}{b_n}\ \ \text{ for all }\ i&\Rightarrow\frac{h_i}{h_n}\le\frac{b_i}{b_n}\ \ \text{ for all }\ i\\
&\Rightarrow\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{h_i}{h_n}\le\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{b_i}{b_n}\\
&\Rightarrow\frac{\sum_\limits{i=1}^nh_i}{\sum_\limits{i=1}^nb_i}\le\frac{h_n}{b_n}
\end{align}
Likewise,
\begin{align}
\frac{h_1}{b_1}\le\frac{h_i}{b_i}\ \ \text{ for all }\ i&\Rightarrow\frac{b_i}{b_1}\le\frac{h_i}{h_1}\ \ \text{ for all }\ i\\
&\Rightarrow\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{b_i}{b_1}\le\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{h_i}{h_1}\\
&\Rightarrow\frac{h_1}{b_1}\le\frac{\sum_\limits{i=1}^nh_i}{\sum_\limits{i=1}^nb_i}
\end{align}

Comment: That's great, no need for anything fancy at all. Thanks!